# Should someone with a PhD be called "Doctor"?

Tags: phd

Should someone who holds a PhD be called Doctor? Should they not be refered to as Mr./Ms. J.Doe, PhD occupation title? It seems wrong to put a "Doctorate" designation in front of someones name who holds a higher degree. If a person held both degrees, Dr. J Doe (occupation) PhD might be appropriate, but otherwise, I think each, individually, by themselves should hold prominence. Doctor of this ,PhD of that. Does this sound correct?

Comment: PhD is an abbreviation. I suggest you look up what it is an abbreviation of.